# What's the difference between "tier" and "layer"?

Tags: meaning

What's the difference between "tier" and "layer"?
When should I use "tier" and when should I use "layer"?

Comment: What do the dictionaries say?

Comment: @MetaEd, I did try to find answers on the web for a while. Only after feeling the frustration of not being able to find answers I posted the question here. Yet, I didn't feel like "I search the web to no avail" to indicate my research would have helped make the question clearer.

Comment: migrate to English Language Learners?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering only the common "**spatial arrangement**" definitions of the words, the difference between the two can be subtle:

**layers (arrangement)** are: similar sheets/strata placed one above another in succession.

**tiers (arrangement)** are: similar sheets/strata placed one above another in succession **AND** *each successive level being **offset from each other** (horizontally or in some other meaningful way)*.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/layer

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/tier

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/stratum

Comment: I like your  answer with user1535037's pictures. Thank you both.

Answer (score 7):

Think of a cake.

These are the layers of a cake.[image]

these are the tiers of a cake.
[image]

The words are similar in that they mean level, but layer talks about something that is **one** which is made out of **many different levels**, while **tier** is more about **many different pieces** in a bigger picture, such as hierarchy.

Comment: Pictures are worth a thousand words. Very picturesque. https://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/A+picture+is+worth+a+thousand+words

Comment: +1 for a picturesque answer, but I'm not sure it is the whole story. Some cakes have layers, others e.g. wedding cakes have tiers, buildings have storeys or levels. They have their similarities, but as with so much in our language, idiom governs what is considered "correct".

Comment: I like these pictures with user22542's answer. Thank you both.

Comment: May I have a piece of each? :)

Answer (score -3):

"Layer" goes for certain surfaces or objects that divides else things from one and another.

"Tier" use for to specify its level of goodness or badness